# jQuery - click() not working when attached to anchor created in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, click

I have this PHP code which outputs HTML anchor elements on a page:

```
            if(!$isOnOwnPage)
                    echo '<a id="message-button" class="button">Message</a>';
                if($isOnOwnPage)
                    echo '<a id="add-img-button" class="button">Add Image';
                else if(!$isFollowing)
                    echo '<a id="follow-button" class="button">Follow';
                else
                    echo '<a id="follow-button" class="button">Unfollow';
                echo "</a>";
```

When I load the web page, I get this, as expected:

```
...    
<a id="message-button" class="button">Message</a><a id="follow-button" class="button">Unfollow</a>          
...
```

But when I try to attach a click() function to it, the clicking doesn't work. This is the jQuery code. (It's weird because all of my other JS on the page works flawlessly."

```
$('.button').click(function() { alert("HEY"); }); // It doesn't work grabbing by #follow-button or #message-button either.
```

**What did I do wrong here? I've spent an hour looking at these snippets of code to no avail.**

Comment: When/how do these links get loaded? Try $('.button').live('click') instead, does that work?

Comment: You must have another js error somewhere that's killing you. Have you checked in your console? Your code here works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/QWP68/

Comment: No errors, all of my other jQuery works. And the button.click() code snippet is the first line in document.ready

Comment: @Johnny Have you examined the `$('.button')` object? What DOM elements does it contain?

Comment: Is your jQuery code enclosed in something like `$(document).ready(function() {...});`?

Comment: @Johnny OK, is see that you didn't understand my comment. Just run this code on document ready: `alert( $('.button').length );`. If it alerts 0, then there are no `.button` elements on the page.

Comment: GOT IT. THE PHP I ECHOED IN THE JQUERY SCRIPT BROKE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`$('.button').live('click',function() { alert("HEY"); });`

Put it in your `$(document).ready` function.

Comment: one or the other, don't bother with both.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna go out on a limb and guess that you've forgotten to wait for `document.ready` and that the `a.button` element doesn't exist when the `click` event is bound.

Comment: No. I do have document.ready, and I do wait before clicking. All of my other anchor click handlers work fine, except this one.

Answer (score 0):

Is ajax included somehow? Because then you need to either use the live, or re-apply the function.

Answer (score 0):

It should work regardless if it's PHP generated. In the end it's still HTML that gets output to the client.

I think you should make sure that the JS code gets to the part where you assign clicks to the buttons. Maybe there's not document ready or a correct one. Maybe there's a boolean IF that doesn't get passed.

All in all, if you can see the code in the View Source page, then it's a HTML/JS problem, not a PHP one.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but to all there who want to add listeners to dynamic content, instead of using `$('a').(click(function(){})` or `$('a').on('click',function(){})`, you need to use instead the **document** as the object you want to attach the listeners, because the tag you are inserting wasn't in the DOM when the listener was assigned.

So instead you should use:

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(){ ... });
```